# insert statement for enter data into a nested field in big query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

is there any way that i can enter data in address.code using insert statement. attached is table screenshot

eg:

something like that

insert into my_project.my_dataset.test_table(name,address.code) select myname,[STRUCT('ABC')] from tab1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va8Ma.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are fairly close to what you want. `address` is a column of type `RECORD`, so you want to use the type `struct` in your `insert` statement:

```sql
insert into my_project.my_dataset.test_table(address) 
select struct(line1 as line1, line2 as line2, code as code)
from tab1
```

Comment: Thanks , but we want to insert data in only one nested col at a time..for eg here i just want to insert value for address.code

Comment: Since the column is of type nullable, you can use the `to_json_string(null)` function or simply quote `'null'`.  And for integer columns, just write `null`.